# How to publish message in ZeroMQ with least latency possible?

Tags: zeromq

Suppose I have a process with pub socket and another process with sub socket.
How do I configure these 2 sockets such that the message I send from pub socket arrives to sub socket with the least latency possible?

My intuition is to set high water mark value to 1 because it's a queue buffer that is filled before message is sent. So if the queue is big it means the message will be queued for long. But I don't care about order of the message. I only care that the latest message is sent as fast as possible. The message is kind of a state. The sub socket must always have the latest state of pub socket.

Note: You can assume TCP protocol and the processes are on the same machine.

Comment: Your assumption about the high water mark is not correct. It is a limit on the internal buffer size. When the client processes messages slower than the server sends them, the high water mark will eventually block the server from sending more messages.

Comment: AFAIK, ZeroMQ will immediately send the messsage over TCP/IP when you call `zmq_send()`, unless you use `ZMQ_SNDMORE`.

Comment: So you are saying that ZeroMQ will try to send the message as quickly as possible and I cannot modify any parameters to make it faster?

Comment: Yes. Or do you have any evidence that would suggest that ZeroMQ does not send it immediately?